# Amazon IAP Plugin for Xamarin - crash when using TaskCompletionSource

Tags: xamarin, task-parallel-library, taskcompletionsource, amazon-in-app-purchase

I'm trying to implement a wrapper for the Amazon IAP Plugin for Xamarin. It uses an event based system in the following way:

> You can initiate method calls and listen for events. Method calls initiate requests, some of which return a response. Events are asynchronous system-generated messages that are sent in response to method calls to return the requested data to you.
>   [See more here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/docs-v2/using-the-iap-plugin-for-xamarin)

My goal is to wrap this event based system into some API which allows me to use the plugin with tasks, so I can use the `async-await` syntax. To achieve that I'm using the `TaskCompletionSource` like in the following example:

```
public async Task<bool> GetProductInfoAsync(params string[] productIds)
{
    var iapService = AmazonIapV2Impl.Instance;
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    var skus = new SkusInput { Skus = productIds.ToList() };
    var requestId = iapService.GetProductData(skus).RequestId;

    GetProductDataResponseDelegator delegator = null;
    delegator = new GetProductDataResponseDelegator(response => 
    {
        if(response.Id == requestId) {
            var result = GetResultFromResponse(response);
            tcs.SetResult(result);
            //iapService.RemoveGetProductDataResponseListener(delegator.responseDelegate);
        }
    });

    iapService.AddGetProductDataResponseListener(delegator.responseDelegate);
    return await tcs.Task;
}
```

This code seems to work fine if the method gets called once, but if it gets called two times in a row the app crashes immediately and the only thing printed to the console is the following message..

```
[mono] Unhandled Exception:
[mono] System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
[mono-rt] [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

..which kinda makes no sense at all.

So is there something obvious I'm missing here? Or could it be a bug from the plugin?

I have created a repository with the code above so you can reproduce the problem. It's my playground, so please ignore the whole structure of the project and just focus on the classes [AmazonIAPService](https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/PlayGround/blob/amazon_iap/PlayGround.UI.Droid/Services/AmazonIAPService.cs) and [MainActivity](https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/PlayGround/blob/amazon_iap/PlayGround.UI.Droid/Views/MainActivity.cs).

*Hint 1:*
The commented line `//iapService.RemoveGetProductDataResponseListener(delegator.responseDelegate);` causes also a crash with the same message but already at the first call of the method.

*Hint 2:*
The `AmazonIAPService` contains a commented method which uses `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1))` and solves the problem from above in a very hacky way which I really don't like.

Comment: regarding RemoveGetProductDataResponseListener, it could be problem that because you are trying remove inside the delagator, it is like removing an element from a List while you are looping that list.

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be that those functions have to run asynchronously. Also mentioned [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/cross-platform-plugins/cpp-use-the-iap-plugin-for-xamarin.html#methods-and-events) in the doc. So once you run those functions synchronously somehow they throw exception, i dont what is happening in the library but your hacky solution is the actual solution for that. If you write the function as below. it also works.

```
  PurchaseResponseDelegator delegator = null;
                delegator = new PurchaseResponseDelegator(async response =>
                {
                    await Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        if (response.RequestId == requestId)
                        {
                            var result = GetPurchaseEventHandler(response);
                            var sucess = taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(result);        
                            context.RemovePurchaseResponseListener(delegator.responseDelegate);
                        }
                    } );
                });
                // Register for an event
                context.AddPurchaseResponseListener(delegator.responseDelegate);
```

One other exception I had despite the async-await solution, somehow, it always throws exception for the line `taskCompletionSource.SetResult(result);` for PurchaseUpdates functions only. if i use instead this line  `var sucess = taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(result);` it works fine